# How to navigate dialog to fragment in android kotlin

Tags: android, kotlin, navigation, dialog

I have button in dialog, when I click that button I need to navigate to the fragment in android kotlin

Here is my nav_graph

```
 <fragment
    android:id="@+id/congratulationsDialog"
    android:name="com.boast.betting.popup.CongratulationsDialog"
    android:label="congratulations_dialog"
    tools:layout="@layout/congratulations_dialog" >
    <action
        android:id="@+id/action_congratulationsDialog_to_newBoastFragment"
        app:destination="@id/newBoastFragment"
        app:enterAnim="@anim/from_left"
        app:exitAnim="@anim/to_right"
        app:popEnterAnim="@anim/from_right"
        app:popExitAnim="@anim/to_left" />
</fragment>
```

DialogClass

```
 binding.createNewBoastButton.setOnClickListener {
        view?.let { it1 ->
            parentFragment?.view?.let { it2 -> Navigation.findNavController(it2).navigate(R.id.action_congratulationsDialog_to_homeFragment) };
        }
```

Comment: Why not use the action you created instead of using the layout id? Btw, what problem are you facing with this code?

Comment: I can't able to navigate from dialogFragment to fragment, Can you please say how can I navigate from dialogFragment to fragment

Comment: Do you get any error while navigating? Any compile time or run time error?

Comment: No I don't get any error message for this, the problem is action is not happening

Comment: The id in your ``navigate`` call doesn't match the one in the XML ``action``

Comment: So what is correct way

Comment: Something like `findNavController.navigate(CongratulationsDialogDirections. actionCongratulationsDialogToNewBoastFragment())`

Comment: CongratulationsDialogDirections shows error like Unresolved reference: CongratulationsDialogDirections